# Get list, start/stop processes of lan server/pc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lan

I have multiple PCs and servers in my LAN. Now I want to build a ASP.NET or Windows Forms Application which controls the running processes of all servers and PCs.

Is there a way to get a list of the running processes of remote server/pc? And is there a way to start/stop processes the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You can't write a ASP.NET Windows Form Application . You have go for either windows application or ASP.NET Web Application. In this Above case it is Windows Application.  You can do it in two methods,

1. Some Program running in all the client machines which will collect process information to the server application.
2. Using WMI, using Win32_Process class.

I would suggest WMI approach if you have clients running Windows OS.